Help! My strawberries won’t clone
I’ve tried store bought plants, seeds, bare roots, and transplants. I’m only partially successful. So I want to clone my strawberries, but I don’t know where to take them from and the best way to propagate them. I have Clonex supplement, so that’s not my problem. I’m in zone 7, so pretty much everything grows here that’s not tropical, even pistachio and kiwi.
I’m aiming for encircling a medium-sized fence, so just letting the runners spread isn’t going to get me where I want to be in my lifetime

Don't the runners do just that?

@YosefBaskin I have one strawberry in my ornamental garden (there for a specific reason) and it's pretty much a weed thanks to all the runners.

How big is a medium sized fence?

What variety of strawberry? You can cut the runners from the mother plant in the fall and transplant to where you want. My afore-mentioned strawberry has at least a dozen runners each year, and each runner, if not weeded out, can produce at least 3-4 the next year. This makes for dozens of clones after only two or three seasons.

I agree with the other responses here: assuming you have even one live strawberry plant, you can wait till it's strong enough to produce runners. Let those runners do their thing (or lead them where you want your extra strawberries to live). I had one 'wild seedling' of strawberry in my garden, between stones. I pulled it out, put it in water, turns out there were 4 little plants in that clump. I replanted them where I wanted them and am now waiting for them to grow to size. All 4 are quite healthy, just very small so far.

slightly differently to @Jurp I tend to plant my runners in pots  while they're still attached to the parent, and cut them off later

You may also want to google "propagation by layering" - ie take part of it that is along the ground and cover it with soil.    This will encourage it to root.   You can then sever the runner.

First I would check the I’m only partially successful. I think you should find out the problem: wrong soil? wrong tumidity? Parasites? Only when you solve such problem I think you can clone successful: note runners growth at end of season (starting with summer): in spring they plants are busy with fruits (main propagation mean), later with the second propagation methods).
